# Remove gap between UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make flexible collectionview with free height. but i couldn't remove the extra gap between cells vertically.

```
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionView.register(MultilineLabelCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MultilineLabelCell.reuseId)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    collectionView.frame = self.view.bounds
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MultilineLabelCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! MultilineLabelCell
    cell.configure(note: viewModel.notes![indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return viewModel.notes!.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let referenceHeight: CGFloat = 100 // Approximate height of cell
    let referenceWidth = collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width/2.2
    return CGSize(width: referenceWidth, height: referenceHeight)
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's normal behavior. It sets a line, and the height for that line is the max height of the elements on that line, centering the other elements vertically (that's how you see it, per line, not per column, you'll see the "centering" then, and not the "gap". That's the normal behavior of default UICollectionViewLayout. You need to use a custom one. See: https://imgur.com/8RYGbrK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a UICollectionView like this.

[image: UICollectionView with item floating height]

To do this, I use the following code for a custom UICollectionViewLayout in my application (I am not changing it, but the approach itself is easy to understand)

```
import UIKit

protocol StoryAppCollectionLayoutDelegate: AnyObject {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
}

class StoryAppCollectionLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

weak var delegate: StoryAppCollectionLayoutDelegate?
private var numberOfColumns = 2
private let cellPadding: CGFloat = 6
private var cache: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
private var previousBounds: CGRect?
private var previousNumberOfColumns : Int?

private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
      return 0
    }
    let insets = collectionView.contentInset
    return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
}

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}

override func prepare() {
    if let collectionView = collectionView {

        numberOfColumns = Int(collectionView.bounds.width / CARD_ITEM_SIZE)
        if previousNumberOfColumns == numberOfColumns {
            return
        }
        previousNumberOfColumns = numberOfColumns
        
        cache.removeAll()
        
        let columnWidth = CARD_ITEM_SIZE // contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset: [CGFloat] = []
        for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset: [CGFloat] = .init(repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)
        
        contentHeight = 0
        for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            

            let photoHeight = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath) ?? 180
            let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column],
                             y: yOffset[column],
                             width: columnWidth,
                             height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)
            
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

            column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
        }
        collectionView.contentSize.height = contentHeight
        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        if collectionView.contentOffset.y > contentHeight - collectionView.bounds.height {
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row:(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var visibleLayoutAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

    // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
    for attributes in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
        visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    let shouldIvalidate = newBounds != self.previousBounds
    if shouldIvalidate {
        if let collectionView = self.collectionView, collectionView.bounds.width > 0 {
            let cWidth = CGFloat(numberOfColumns) * CARD_ITEM_SIZE
            let sideInsets = (collectionView.bounds.width - cWidth) / 2
            collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: cellPadding, left: sideInsets, bottom: cellPadding, right: sideInsets)
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
    self.previousBounds = newBounds
    return false
}
    
}
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return CARD_ITEM_SIZE * image.size.height / image.size.width
}
```

Hope this helps to understand the approach.

NB.
I use a non-fixed number of elements horizontally because this application using MacCatalyst also works on MacOS with automatic resizing of UICollectionView items when the application window is resized.
On iPhone / iPad can be used in any orientation too.

Comment: can you say, how we can use "shouldInvalidateLayout" ?

Comment: In this case, we keep the old bound value so that we can compare them. Then, if necessary, recalculate the values of the empty space between the elements so that they are evenly spaced horizontally. Inside I call recalculation (collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()) and therefore already answer UICollectionView that no more peering layout is needed (return false).